# How can I decrease my Rails test overhead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd

I'm using Test::Unit on a large app with a large number of gem dependencies (>75).  I'm trying to develop using BDD, but it takes minutes for the app to load it's dependencies before it can run the tests.  Is there a way to preload the dependencies and just auto-run the test on changes, or a similar solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using RSpec and there's a great tool for it, called [Spork](http://spork.rubyforge.org/). It basically loads your app once and then just reloads modified parts. If you combine it with [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), you get "continuous testing". That is, you hit 'Save' in your editor and tests start executing, giving you instant feedback. This still amazes me after some months :)

#### Edit

As @THEM points out, there's a plugin for Spork to support TestUnit. You should look into it.

Comment: Thanks, Spork + Guard has helped immensely

Answer (score 2):

I would look into Spork.  It works wonders.

https://github.com/sporkrb/spork

https://github.com/sporkrb/spork-testunit

Answer (score 0):

There was also [an interesting article](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2742-the-road-to-faster-tests) about test speed on the 37Signals blog a while back. Might be of interest even if you end up going with Spork or another solution.